# How to deal with users spamming one-line questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, new-users, low-quality

Several users joined yesterday to start a spree on creating masses of questions (and some answers) with

- only one line
- clearly no research (most of them are closed)
- no formatting
- no proper tagging

How to deal with such users? I tried the comment & welcome & could you imrpove foo & bar thingy, but some seem resistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just continue to downvote and close. We don't want to discourage new users, so a nice comment to suggest improvements would be nice, but if it is a repeat offender I think a flag or vote to close is sufficient.

Most of the problem questions have been closed, and I think the problem will go away with time.

Answer (score 2):

Just downvote them, and if the answer is also full of typos or intelligble, flag as Very Low Quality. When users get downvoted in a large part of their posts, they get locked from answering automatically.

Comment: i noticed that even very low quality posts keep getting upvotes (some even +5 and more) on this quite young and enthusiastic community.

Comment: @5chdn Well, then perhaps there is some educating about good voting behavior necessary. Also, flags circumvent voting by going directly to the moderators, they can still delete a VLQ post with positive score.